# I want the result goes to main page

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, asp-classic, onsubmit

I'm having a difficult time in getting to work this out, Im new to classic asp and javascript. Hope someone will help me clear this out. I want to view the response.write on the main.asp (or the result) but everytime i try this, it goes to pass.asp (on another page) :(

here's my code. main.asp

==================================================================================

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validate() {
document.getElementById("RegDiv").innerHTML =pass.asp;
}
</script>
<style>
#RegDiv {
color:blue;
}

</style>
</head>

<form name="RegForm"  action="reg.asp" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" />
<table border="1">
<tr><td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
<tr><td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register"></td></tr>

</table>`</form>
<div id="RegDiv"></div>
</html>
```

and here's my reg.asp

```
<%
fname = Request.Form("fname")
lname = Request.Form("lname")
Email = Request.Form("email")
Username = Request.Form("user")
Password = Request.Form("pass")

getSub = Request.Form("Submit")

if getSub="Register" then

Dim goby
goby=0

if len(Email)<= 5 then
goby=1
end if

if Instr(1, Email, "@", 1) <2 then
goby=1
else

if Instr(1, Email, ".", 1) <4 then
goby=1

end if
end if

if fname="" then
response.write("Please provide your first name")

elseif lname="" then
response.write("Please provide your last name")

elseif Email="" then
response.write("Please provide your email")

elseif goby<>0 then
response.write("<span style='#F00'>Please provide a real email address!</span>")

elseif Username
response.write("Please provide your Username")

elseif Password="" then
response.write("Please provide your Password")

else
response.write("Your form was processed successfully")
end if

end if
%>
```

Comment: what is in your `pass.asp` page ? And what is the validate function meant to do ?

Comment: And this: `elseif Username` in your `reg.asp` page should be `elseif Username="" then`

Comment: Yes i just forgot that elseif Username="" thanks for reminding me. "what is in your pass.asp page?" -that's all there is. " And what is the validate function meant to do ? " they are working good but i wanted the response.write to show on the main.asp NOT on the pass.asp page.

Comment: `"what is in your pass.asp page?" -that's all there is.`  You have shown main.asp and reg.asp. I don't see code for pass.asp anywhere..  as for the response.write, it will be shown in reg.asp since you have written the code there. If you want it in main.asp itself, then you write the code in main.asp and change the `action` to main.asp instead of reg.asp.

Comment: Im sorry i was confused. the pass.asp is the reg.asp! I want the response.write to show on the main.asp NOT on the reg.asp page. You suggest to write the code on the main.asp and change the action to main.asp, Yes i think that is possible but is there any other way to separate main.asp and reg.asp but still show the result or response.write on the main.asp? is it possible to embed javascript or onsubmit.. I need to separate main.asp and reg.asp

Comment: You can modify the validate function in your `main.asp` to validate your form entries and show javascript alerts to the user . Please do a search for `javascript+form+validation` and try out.

Answer (score 0):

your code is... strange at best. you have a return on a function with no return value that should do nothing and you use your submit button for detecting if a user is registering. try changing your code to this and see if if helps at all.

Changes:

removed return action from form onSubmit

added hidden value to check if registering

had javascript set form value for submit type

**Edit:** added an inclued sataement to merge main and reg.asp into one page

**Edit:** changed action of form to main.asp

**Edit:** fixed some typos

**Edit:** changed = to StrComp function

**Edit:** forgot to add id to hidden value

**Edit:** removed StrComp for empty strings as it caused errors

**Main.asp**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
 function validate() {
 // removed as it will happen and then user will be sent to the next page
 // so the user will never see it
 //document.getElementById("RegDiv").innerHTML =pass.asp;

 document.getElementById('subtype').value = "Register";
 }
 </script>
 <style>
 #RegDiv {
 color:blue;
 }

 </style>
</head>
<!--#include virtual="reg.asp"-->
  <form name="RegForm" action="main.asp" method="post" onsubmit="validate();" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subtype" id="subtype" value="">
    <table border="1">
      <tr><td>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>last Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
      <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
      <tr><td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register"></td></tr>

    </table>`</form>
  <div id="RegDiv"></div>
</html>
```

**reg.asp**

```
<%
  fname = Request.Form("fname")
  lname = Request.Form("lname")
  Email = Request.Form("email")
  Username = Request.Form("user")
  Password = Request.Form("pass")

  getSub = Request.Form("subtype")

  if StrComp(getSub,"Register", 1)+1 then

    Dim goby
    goby=0

    if len(Email)<= 5 then
      goby=1
    end if

    if Instr(1, Email, "@", 1) <2 then
      goby=1
    else

      if Instr(1, Email, ".", 1) <4 then
        goby=1

      end if
    end if

    if fname ="" OR fname = vbNullString then
    response.write("Please provide your first name")

    ElseIf lname="" OR lname=vbNullString then
      response.write("Please provide your last name")

    ElseIf Email="" OR Email=vbNullString then
      response.write("Please provide your email")

    ElseIf goby<>0 then
      response.write("<span style='#F00'>Please provide a real email address!</span>")

    ElseIf Username="" OR Username=vbNullString then
      response.write("Please provide your Username")

    ElseIf Password="" OR Password=vbNullString then
      response.write("Please provide your Password")

    else
      response.write("Your form was processed successfully")
    end if

  end if
%>
```

The main thing I think broke your original code was that JavaScript return function. because you did not have quotes around pass.asp the function likely took that as the return value you needed to generate and was passing you to that page before the post action actually happened.

Comment: Thanks for your correction I did all your suggestion, but it seems, everytime i completed registration it still direct to reg.asp but now without any response.write even the success registration message.

Comment: make sure the action in your form is changed to main.asp. If it is still a problem refresh the page to make sure that the old page is not cached in the browser for any reason.

Comment: Thanks it's more clearer now! I can see the registration message on the main page. but the only result showing is the "Please provide your first name" even if after signing up successfully.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me through. I put back the original code for the if's.. then it went smooth just what i wanted. Thanks again maestro!